# Sending alert mail to store owner in opencart is not working

Tags: opencart

I am using opencart version 1.5.6.4, till now it was working fine. I wanted to send alert mail to store owner when new customer register so I enabled alert mail as "yes".

Now my problem is when I customize html mail content the customer to receive, store owner is also getting the same mail. Please refer the code below

```
$subject = sprintf($this->language->get('text_subject'), $this->config->get('config_name'));

    $message1 = sprintf($this->language->get('text_welcome'), $this->config->get('config_name')) . "\n\n";

    if (!$customer_group_info['approval']) {
        $message1 .= $this->language->get('text_login') . "\n";
    } else {
        $message1 .= $this->language->get('text_approval') . "\n";
    }

    $message1 .= $this->url->link('account/login', '', 'SSL') . "\n\n";
    $message1 .= $this->language->get('text_services') . "\n\n";
    $message1 .= $this->language->get('text_thanks') . "\n";
    $message1 .= $this->config->get('config_name');
    $message1 .='<body>';
    $message1 .='<tr>';
    $message1 .='<td align="center" valign="top" width="100%" style="background-color: #f7f7f7; height: 100px;">';
    $message1 .='<center>';
    $message1 .='<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="600" class="w320">';
    $message1 .='<tr>';
    $message1 .='<td style="padding: 25px 0 25px;text-align:center">';
    $message1 .='<strong style="text-align:center;">BOOK MY MAGAZINE</strong><br />';
    $message1 .='© 2015 Bookmymagazine.com. <br />';
    $message1 .='All Rights Reserved<br /><br />';
    $message1 .='</td>';
    $message1 .='</tr>';
    $message1 .='</table>';
    $message1 .='</center>';
    $message1 .='</td>';
    $message1 .='</tr>';

    $message1 .='</body>';


    $mail = new Mail();
    $mail->protocol = $this->config->get('config_mail_protocol');
    $mail->parameter = $this->config->get('config_mail_parameter');
    $mail->hostname = $this->config->get('config_smtp_host');
    $mail->username = $this->config->get('config_smtp_username');
    $mail->password = $this->config->get('config_smtp_password');
    $mail->port = $this->config->get('config_smtp_port');
    $mail->timeout = $this->config->get('config_smtp_timeout');             
    $mail->setTo($data['email']);
    $mail->setFrom($this->config->get('config_email'));
    $mail->setSender($this->config->get('config_name'));
    $mail->setSubject(html_entity_decode($subject, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
    $mail->setHtml(html_entity_decode($message1, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
    $mail->send();

    // Send to main admin email if new account email is enabled
    if ($this->config->get('config_account_mail')) {
        $message  = $this->language->get('text_signup') . "\n\n";
        $message .= $this->language->get('text_website') . ' ' . $this->config->get('config_name') . "\n";
        $message .= $this->language->get('text_firstname') . ' ' . $data['firstname'] . "\n";
        $message .= $this->language->get('text_lastname') . ' ' . $data['lastname'] . "\n";
        $message .= $this->language->get('text_customer_group') . ' ' . $customer_group_info['name'] . "\n";

        if ($data['company']) {
            $message .= $this->language->get('text_company') . ' '  . $data['company'] . "\n";
        }

        $message .= $this->language->get('text_email') . ' '  .  $data['email'] . "\n";
        $message .= $this->language->get('text_telephone') . ' ' . $data['telephone'] . "\n";

        $mail->setTo($this->config->get('config_email'));
        $mail->setSubject($this->language->get('text_new_customer'));
        $mail->setText($message);
        $mail->send();

        // Send to additional alert emails if new account email is enabled
        $emails = explode(',', $this->config->get('config_alert_emails'));

        foreach ($emails as $email) {
            if (strlen($email) > 0 && preg_match('/^[^\@]+@.*\.[a-z]{2,6}$/i', $email)) {
                $mail->setTo($email);
                $mail->send();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems the issue with $message variable. May be you haven't applied comment to it, not sure. Define $message where the admin mail design starts. I would suggest to do following  `$message='';` after `if ($this->config->get('config_account_mail')) {` may solve your problem.

Comment: have you tried to print what $message contains. Try `print_r($message); exit;`  and then do a new registration. Which may help to understand more clear.

Comment: When i do print_r($message);exit(); i get the correct mail which admin has to receive but as soon as i comment it again i get the same mail which customer receive. Is their any alternative to send html mail other than as setHtml because whenever i ste it to set Html this problem occurs

Comment: Thanks i have solved it by myself by adding a new mail object to admi's mail part